# Why does $(1)$ imply $(2)$?

Tags: measure-theory, convergence-divergence, measurable-functions

Let $\mathcal{V}=\mathcal{V}(S,T)$ be the class of functions $f(t,\omega):[0,\infty)\times\Omega\to\mathbb{R}$ such that $(t,\omega)\to f(t,\omega)$ is $\mathcal{B}\times\mathcal{F}$-measurable (where $\mathcal{B}$ denotes the Borel $\sigma$-algebra on $[0,\infty)$), $f(t,\omega)$ is $\mathcal{F}_t$-adapted and $\mathbb{E}\bigg[\int_{S}^T f(t,\omega)^2 dt\bigg]<\infty$. 
If $f\in\mathcal{V}$ one can show that it is possible to choose elementary functions $\phi_n\in\mathcal{V}$ such that:
$$\mathbb{E}\left[\int_S^T|f-\phi_n|^2 dt\right]\to0\tag{1}$$
I know that $(1)$ implies that:
$$\mathbb{E}\left[\int_S^T|\phi_n(t)-\phi_m(t)|^2 dt\right]\to0\tag{2}$$

---

---

---

Could you please help me understand why $(1)$ implies $(2)$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

\begin{align}
E\left[\int_S^T|\phi_n(t)-\phi_m(t)|^2 dt\right]&=E\left[\int_S^T|\phi_n(t)-f(t)+f(t)-\phi_m(t)|^2 dt\right] \\
&\leq E\left[\int_S^T 2|\phi_n(t)-f(t)|^2+2|f(t)-\phi_m(t)|^2 dt\right]  \\
&= 2E\left[\int_S^T |\phi_n(t)-f(t)|^2\right]+2E\left[\int_S^T|f(t)-\phi_m(t)|^2 dt\right] \rightarrow 0.
\end{align}
The '$\leq$' follows from the elementary inequality $(a+b)^2 \leq 2a^2 + 2b^2$ and the convergence to zero from (1).